# Easiest way to solve system of two equations and two variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a linear system of two equations with two variables, such that
$$53172 = 137t_1 + 215t_2$$
$$81743 = 312t_1 − 187t_2$$

What is the easiest way to get the value of $t_1$ and $t_2$?
I know that I can use methods such [this one](https://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Systems-of-Algebraic-Equations-Containing-Two-Variables), or by using a scientific calculator but I'm looking for an easier method.
Is there any way to get that?

Comment: Cramer's method

Comment: No, I meant by hand

Comment: try cramer's rule

Comment: yes, matrices are doable by hand

Comment: Since there are only two equations and two variables, there is an explicit formula using Cramer's rule ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems)).

Comment: Ok, thanks for everyone, I get it

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180580/are-there-any-other-methods-to-apply-to-solving-simultaneous-equations) (possible duplicate)

Comment: @MrPie yes.....

Comment: @abc... Hello this is George. Nice to meet you. :)